# How to SELECT to find date/time overlap with a unique value?

Tags: mysql

curious how people would efficiently go about solving the following.

Have a simple table that tracks a group of "approvers" for reports.  also tracks when reports are "created" and when they were "submitted."  The time span between creation and submission of reports should be when the approver ID is committed to a single report, BUT if their approver ID shows up inside the same timespan for another report I want to flag it.

Example (one table, "reports"):

```
"Created"                 "Submitted"                "ApproverID"
4/20/2012 5:01:32 AM          4/20/2012 5:30:32 AM          10
4/20/2012 5:08:32 AM          4/20/2012 5:45:32 AM          10
4/20/2012 5:01:32 AM          4/19/2012 5:38:16 PM          15
```

In this example, I'd like to SELECT and return the rows that overlap, which are:

```
 "Created"                 "Submitted"                "ApproverID"     "Duplicate_ID"
4/20/2012 5:01:32 AM          4/20/2012 5:30:32 AM          10            1
4/20/2012 5:08:32 AM          4/20/2012 5:45:32 AM          10            1
```

...and possibly append a new column "Duplicate" with a unique value to report against the specific overlap hits which I could just do a SELECT DISTINCT Duplicate_ID on.

I have played around with BETWEEN but to no avail.  any help appreciated!

thank you

Comment: Is the first submitted created? and second submitted?  I"m confused on the column headers.

Comment: yes, first is created.  my mistake.  any ideas?

Comment: Did Marcu's solution not work?  He's usually pretty good with this too :D

Comment: no, it assumes two tables.  Instead of a JOIN is there a way to show the times the ID overlaps in the same time windows?

Answer (score 0):

UNTESTED:

```
SELECT R1.Created, R1.Submitted, R1.ApproverID, count(*) 
FROM reports R1
INNER JOIN reports R2
  on R1.Created between R2.Created and R2.Submitted --ON
  OR R2.created between R2.Created and R2.submitted --OR
GROUP BY R1.Created, R1.Submitted, R1.ApproverID
```

Comment: You are close but I don't think you need the OR line in the INNER JOIN. The table will also need an index to prevent joining 2 of the same records. You also forgot to check `R1.ApproverID = R2.ApproverID`.

Comment: Ack, sorry...this is one table (I mis-pasted the column names):

Comment: So, in a single table - this is the format. one column for when the timestamp shows report creation, another for report submission:

This is a query from a single table.  The first column header should read "CREATED", and the second "SUBMITTED"    (not 'submitted' and 'submitted')

sorry about that!

"Created" "Submitted" "ApproverID" "Duplicate_ID" 4/20/2012 5:01:32 AM 4/20/2012 5:30:32 AM 10 1 4/20/2012 5:08:32 AM 4/20/2012 5:45:32 AM 10 1

Sorry for the confusion!!!

Answer (score 0):

This gets you a list of the conflicting reports anyway:

```
SELECT r1.approvalID, r2.approvalID
FROM reports r1
JOIN reports r2
  ON r2.approverID = r1.approverID
  AND r2.created < r1.created
  AND r2.submitted >= r1.created
  AND r2.submitted < r1.submitted
```

This assumed you have a primary key named approvalID.